# Jquery Validate Not Working with AngularJs/Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, django, jquery-validate

Hey I am currently doing a web development project using `AngularJS` and `Django`.

Usually for form error messages I use `ngMessages`, but I am trying out Jquery's validate plugin since it seems very straightforward.

However, as straight forward as it is, I cannot seem to get it to work.

I am new to `Jquery` so it's probably a noob mistake.

Here is my code :

**register.html**

```
<div class="header" id="join_header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h1> Join our community </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="supporting-form">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3" data-ng-controller="RegisterController">
        <div class="well">
          <form role="form" id="registrationForm" name="registrationForm" novalidate data-ng-submit="vm.register(registrationForm.$valid)" class="form-horizontal">
            <h4 id="regerror">{{ vm.message }}</h4>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="register__username" class="control-label col-sm-4">Username:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="register__username" data-ng-model="vm.username" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="register__password">Password:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="register__password" id="register__password" data-ng-model="vm.password" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="confirm__password">Confirm Password:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm__password" id="confirm__password" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="register__email">Email:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="register__email" data-ng-model="vm.email" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="register__first_name">First Name:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="register__first_name" data-ng-model="vm.first_name" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="register__last_name">Last Name:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="register__last_name" data-ng-model="vm.last_name" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="register__company">Company:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="register__company" data-ng-model="vm.company" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="register__phone_number">Telephone:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="register__phone_number" data-ng-model="vm.phone_number" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="register__access_code">Access Code:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="register__access_code" data-ng-model="vm.access_code" placeholder="Don't have one? Contact us" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-offset-5" id="submit_btn">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <p id="alreadymember">Already a member? <a href="/login">Login</a></p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#registrationForm").validate();
  });
</script>
```

and here is my javascript inclusion file:

```
{% load compress %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% compress js %}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js" integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bower_components/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/material.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bower_components/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/ripples.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bower_components/underscore/underscore.js' %}"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-cookies.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bower_components/ngDialog/js/ngDialog.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'lib/snackbarjs/snackbar.min.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/hrlite.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/hrlite.routes.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/hrlite.config.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/authentication/authentication.module.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/authentication/services/authentication.service.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/authentication/controllers/register.controller.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/authentication/controllers/login.controller.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/layout/layout.module.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/layout/controllers/navbar.controller.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/profiles/profiles.modules.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/profiles/services/profile.service.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/profiles/controllers/profile.controller.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/profiles/controllers/profile-settings.controller.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/utils/utils.module.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/utils/services/snackbar.service.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascripts/authentication/directives/confirm.directive.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-messages.js"></script>
{% endcompress %}
```

Comment: never seen so many js request , imagine the page load time :))

Comment: FYI: not a good approach to mix jquery and AngularJS. Try to stick to one, its a good habit ;)

Comment: Explain "does not work"... and any console errors?  Also, every single element considered for validation **must** contain a `name` attribute.

Comment: guys i'm running a single page application using angular, where each has its own controller and service and yada yada.. so that explains the amount of javascript but it doesnt matter because django-compressor compresses the file into a single cached file so the page load time is still impressive.

Comment: but in response to @Sparky, jquery is the first script mentioned.

Comment: I missed that part.  Regarding my first comment, assuming you're trying to validate all elements with the `required` attribute, you're missing the `name` attribute on most of them.  The jQuery Validate plugin will not work when you don't have `name` attributes.

Comment: also @Sparky , by not work I mean just flat out does not work. No console errors either. I'll try adding name attributes and see how that goes

Comment: Your code as you've posted it is working for me, at least on the elements containing `name` attributes.  See:  https://jsfiddle.net/4teqqft5/

Comment: Two things: 1. Put `debug: true` as a `.validate()` option and then look at console log. 2. Create a jsFiddle demo that reproduces this issue